# How to set up a Doctrine MongoDB respository in the Symfony 2 service container

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

How do I correctly set up the service container in my Symfony 2 application to support custom Document repositories?

What I have so far is:

```
services:
  acme.repository_user:
    class: Acme\Repository\UserRepository
    arguments: [@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager]
```

However, when I look at the constructor of the `DocumentRepository` class, of which my `UserRepository` inherits, I can see the following arguments:

```
public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm, UnitOfWork $uow, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
```

I seem to have injected the document manager but how do I inject the Unit of Work and the class meta data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to define service as(sorry for xml):

```
<service id="acme.repository_user"
             class="Acme\Repository\UserRepository"
             factory-service="doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager"
             factory-method="getRepository"
             public="false">
    <argument>AcmeBundle:User</argument>
</service>
```

Comment: Ah. Basically pretty much the same as configuring the ORM. Thanks.

Comment: And here is the related doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html